# Rails models with Single Table Inheritance and HABTM

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, relationships, single-table-inheritance

I have a project with 2 models, Game and Team. A Game has two Teams, an away team and a home team. There is a set number of Teams(no more get created) and each will belong to many Games.

I want to be able to do @game.home_team.name instead of @game.teams.find_by_id(@game.home_team_id).first.name. I'm not sure if I can do that without creating two additional models, AwayTeam and HomeTeam, which will have the same columns as Team except for an additional :game_id and maybe :type.

Currently the HABTM relationship between Games and Teams works but I have no way of turning a Team into a HomeTeam or AwayTeam once it belongs to a Game.

**game.rb**

```
class Game < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :teams
  has_one :away_team, -> {where(type:'away')}, class_name: 'Team' 
  has_one :home_team, -> {where(type:'home')}, class_name: 'Team'
end
```

**team.rb**

```
class Team < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_and_belongs_to_many :games
  # has_many :away_teams
  # has_many :home_teams
end

###

# class AwayTeam < Team
#   belongs_to :game
#   belongs_to :team
# end
# class HomeTeam < Team
#   belongs_to :game
#   belongs_to :team
# end
```

**games_controller.rb**

```
def create
  @game = Game.create(game_params)
  @game.teams << Team.find_all_by_id([ @game.away_team_id, @game.home_team_id ])
  @game.away_team = @game.teams.find_by_id(@game.away_team_id)
  @game.home_team = @game.teams.find_by_id(@game.home_team_id)
  @game.save
end
```

Any help would be really appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add one additional model GameTeam and make has_many :through relation

```
  class GameTeam
    belongs_to :game
    belongs_to :team
    validates :team_type, presence: true
  end

  class Game
    has_many :game_teams
    has_may :teams, through: :game_teams
  end
```

Then you can make game.teams to fetch all teams. You can additionally implement scopes of methods to get home or away team by GameTeam type